# What is the right way to handle duplicated factory in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

instantiate angular's factory n number of times.

example:

```
app.factory('FooService', function(){
   return {
       hello: function() {
           return "hello foo first";
       }
   } 
});

app.factory('FooService', function(){
   return {
       hello: function(){
           return "hello foo second";
       }
   } 
});
```

Second service will override the first one - demo at http://plnkr.co/edit/FNqDdH5w5ArbJEBsgsLc?p=preview

The example is just to illustrate the problem but the real world problem is different developer defined the service with same name which make it very hard to troubleshoot.

What is the right way to handle duplicated factory in angularjs? (or prevent or detect it easily)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what is the right way, however you can ask the `injector` if a particular service exists or not.

```
var myModule = angular.module('myModule', [])
        .factory('test', function () {
            return { test: 'test' };    
        });

var injector = angular.injector(['myModule']);

console.log(injector.has('test')); //true
```

Also note that the service must have been defined prior to the injector retrieval meaning that you shouldn't try to cache the `injector`, just query it every time.

Comment: Do you means that I need to always use injector to check whether service has been defined or not before I define the service?

Comment: @hutingung Well, there might be another way, but that's what I'm suggesting, yes. I also mean that you always have to query for the injector instance everytime before asking it a question, otherwise the answer might be stale.

Comment: thanks. I will accept your answer if there is not better answer in 1 day. I think I will make it a practice to check the service before define it. Beside, I not understand with your statement "... before asking it a question, otherwise the answer might be stale"

Answer (score 0):

This is a perfect use case for a [Decorator](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/%24provide#decorator).

> **Decorator**
>   A service decorator intercepts the creation of a service, allowing it to override or modify the behaviour of the service. The object returned by the decorator may be the original service, or a new service object which replaces or wraps and delegates to the original service.

How to use it:

```
app.config(function($provide) {
  $provide.decorator('FooService', FooServiceDecorator);

  function FooServiceDecorator($delegate) {
    $delegate.hello = function() {
      return "hello foo second";
    };
    return $delegate;
  }
});
```

[Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/gYs1cqw6evc7P9XMXZCM?p=preview)

Comment: Esteban Felix, I think you misunderstand my question. I don't want to override the service but to resolve the problem when developer defined service with the same name. How to prevent that? Example like warning.